# Python: how to get coordinates on mouse click using matplotlib.canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates

I am writing a class to process images. In that class, I want to define a method that can allow me to return coordinates of the mouse clicks. I can get the coordinates as an attribute but if I call the method to return the coordinates, I get an empty tuple

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fname = 'image.jpg'
        self.img = cv2.imread(self.fname)
        self.point = ()

    def getCoord(self):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        plt.imshow(self.img)
        cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.__onclick__)
        return self.point

    def __onclick__(self,click):
        self.point = (click.xdata,click.ydata)
        return self.point
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me, as long as I insert `plt.show()` after `mpl_connect` in `getCoord`:

```
def getCoord(self):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.imshow(self.img)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.__onclick__)
    plt.show()
    return self.point
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it is working for me as well. Now I agree with my professor who once said that "it's harder to debug your own code than someone else" . Omitting that line, made me spending hours trying to find the bug. Thanks a lot